# Why did I get classified as 'Most honorable'?

Tags: goldeneye-007

Yesterday, I was playing the wonderful Goldeneye, for the n64 with a few friends.  We ended up playing a match, first to 10 kills.

I won the match by going 10 (kills) and 2 (deaths).  At the end screen, it shows the watch with some stats about who killed who and two descriptive statements about how you played.

I ended up with 'Most Honorable' and 'Longest Innings'.  Besides 'Longest innings', how are those descriptive statements determined? I thought I did pretty well...

Comment: Your title says Dishonorable, your question says Honorable...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Honorable and Dishonorable are related to how often you shoot players in the back. They aren't a measure of how many kills or deaths you got.

> > **Double Kill**   If you manage to kill two players at one time.
> >
> > **Triple Kill**   Self-explanatory--kill three at once.
> >
> > **Quadruple Kill**    Smooth move, you killed everybody.
> >
> > **AC-10** When you get all the body armor.
> >
> > **Most Deadly**   For the most kills, generally going to the best player.
> >
> > ***Most Honorable***   Plays fair and doesn't shoot in the back much.
> >
> > **Most Professional** No fooling around, mostly head shots, etc.
> >
> > **Marksmanship Award**    For being on the mark the best.
> >
> > **Longest Innings**   The one who stays alive the longest.
> >
> > **Most Cowardly** When you run away and hide a lot.
> >
> > **Most Dishonorable** Shooting people in the back.
> >
> > **Most Frantic**  Running all over the place in chaos.
> >
> > **Mostly Harmless**   Hardly kills anyone.
> >
> > **Where's The Armor?**    Didn't find any armor.
> >
> > **Where's The Ammo?** Got hardly any ammo.
> >
> > **Shortest Innings**  The one who stays alive the shortest.
> >
> > **Lemming Award** For the player with the most suicides.

[source](http://www.angelfire.com/tx3/GoldenEye69/awards.html)

Comment: Source seems to be dead; here's a page with more descriptions: http://goldeneye.wikia.com/wiki/Awards